# How to perform UIKit call on mainthread from inside a block

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, uiwebview, objective-c-blocks, nsinvocation

I am trying to push a view controller from inside a callback block. The view controller I want to push contains a UIWebView, which complains that I should call this on the main thread. I tried using NSInvocation to no avail. How can I call `presentModalViewController:animated` on the main thread?

```
[vc requestUserPermissionWithCallback:^(BOOL inGranted)
         {
             if (inGranted)
             {
                 if (serviceType == PXServiceTypeTwitter)
                 {
                     //[ad.rootViewController presentModalViewController:vc animated: YES]; // crashes
                     NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithTarget:ad.rootViewController selector:@selector(presentModalViewController:animated:) retainArguments:YES, vc, YES];
                     [invocation invokeOnMainThreadWaitUntilDone:NO]; // same result
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
             }
         }];
```

error message:

**bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x6b21090: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...**

I am using the category [NSInvocation+CWVariableArguments](http://blog.jayway.com/2010/03/30/performing-any-selector-on-the-main-thread/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `dispatch_get_main_queue()` to get the main thread and then dispatch to it:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // whatever code you want to run on the main thread
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and used

```
performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
```

to solve it.  Hope that helps.