# Huge delay between viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisappear

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios6

Here is the log output

```
2013-03-16 14:02:59.301 Echo[65406:4503] child viewWillDisappear start
2013-03-16 14:02:59.303 Echo[65406:4503] child viewWillDisappear returning
2013-03-16 14:02:59.303 Echo[65406:4503] parent viewWillAppear start
2013-03-16 14:02:59.305 Echo[65406:4503] parent viewWillAppear returning
2013-03-16 14:02:59.307 Echo[65406:4503] parent finished calling popToRootViewControllerAnimated on child.navigationController
2013-03-16 14:03:30.120 Echo[65406:c07] child viewDidDisappear start
2013-03-16 14:03:30.121 Echo[65406:c07] child viewDidDisappear returning
2013-03-16 14:03:30.121 Echo[65406:c07] parent viewDidAppear start
2013-03-16 14:03:30.122 Echo[65406:c07] parent viewDidAppear returning
```

That's a cool 30 seconds between `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear`. What else is going on in between there?

Comment: Why are you using popToRootViewController:animated: on your parent? You are removing one controller, presenting new one, then removing the new one by calling a method to an object from the removed one.

Comment: To put this is context: parent segues to child in nav controller and sets self as child's delegate, child sends "I'm done" to delegate, parent calls popToRootViewControllerAnimated on child's nav controller

Comment: Does the "child" navigation stack go any further?

Comment: Nope, just two levels total here

Comment: And what's the popToRootViewController:animated: for?

Comment: Parent would like child to pop off of the navigation controller

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26304/discussion-between-devfly-and-full-decent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was threads. It is because this action was in a callback from AFNetworking code. Instead of using:

```
[controller.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Needed:

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411271/how-to-perform-uikit-call-on-mainthread-from-inside-a-block
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [controller.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
});
```