# Delay between viewWillDisappear and viewDidDissapear

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, optimization, uiview

I'm seeing some performance degradation in my application after some time and I'm trying to figure out what's going exactly.

I have a complex view controller (VC1) which contains scroll view, few table views inside, some custom cells with horizontal scrolling and custom drawing etc.

After several (around 10) refreshes of all these objects (reloading tables, reposition subviews etc) when I try to call presentViewController to push another view controller above VC1 I can see about 2 seconds delay between `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDissapear`

I tried to profile the app to see if there are memory leaks but couldn't find any. Memory usage grows when view refreshes and switches between different modes, but then it become more or less stable in around 30m.

Works fine in Simulator, but visible slower on iPhone5. And this slowness is visible only when I try to switch `from` that view controller.

I ran a profiler and recorded where these 2 seconds are spent. Here is link to trace file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6402890/trace.trace.zip

Majority of the time spent by UIKit doing layout as I can see.

What can I do to optimize it? Is there way to take may be a snapshot of a view and use it for "leaving view" animation and restore view hierarchy when we're coming back?

**UPDATE**: Adding screenshot for the profiler (click for full resolution):

[image: screenshot]

**UPDATE2**:

After analyzing output from `recursiveDescription` I can see the following:

- In the easiest case I have ~200 lines in the output. And performance is ok.
- When I switch to more complex scenario hierarchy of views growth to ~500 lines, but still performs ok.
- After multiple refreshes this number goes to ~2000 and this is where it become slow. Analyzing output with 2000 views I can see that ~1500 of them belong to hidden cells that are not even displayed in this mode anymore. When I'm refreshing table views cell types change too, and I'm utilizing different cells, but why the cells that are not used anymore are still being in subviews of table views?

Any recommendations?

Comment: If the 10 refreshes (or >10) run fast, then I'd suspect the view controller being presented.  Can you just rule that out by just allocating a vanilla UIViewController and presenting that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The view controller with many vies (VC1) is being present. If I work within it - everything fine. When I need to leave it and present VC2 (which can be any other view controller) - I record willDisappear and didDisappear event inside VC1.

Comment: "any other view controller" might be the answer to my question. I'm asking, "any other, even a not-subclassed UIViewController?".  Then we would be more certain that the problem lies in VC1.

Comment: Yes. I tried replacing "any" VC with an empty instance of UIViewController object. Original delay between two calls is 0.5 seconds and after 10+ refreshes of VC1 this delay is increasing to ~2 seconds. So the problem is inside my VC2. But I'm not sure what to do with it...

Comment: Hmm.  Not sure how to help.  If it's fast when you don't do the refreshes, maybe the way to proceed is to start commenting out stuff you do in the refresh (one at a time, most suspicious first), and see when it speeds up.  Once it speeds up, investigate the last thing you commented.  (also, see here for a shot in the dark http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452763/huge-delay-between-viewwilldisappear-and-viewdiddisappear)

Comment: Yeah... I saw that question :) - seems unrelated. My stuff is triggered from the main thread. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: You may want to try to capture the essence of the trace.zip in a screenshot. Mind that in a not too distant future, you will remove that file from your DB account.

Comment: @Till: Makes sense. Adding a screenshot.

Comment: with `[![screenshot][1]][1]` and `[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vvmmp.png` a normal click will open the image in full size.

Comment: I suspect that each time you "refresh" you stack on more layers.

Comment: @HotLicks: I don't think it's the case, since there is no memory leaking

Comment: accumulated views will not show up as leaked memory. It's not leaked; it's got a pointer to it. You just didn't mean to hold onto it. What I'm describing in my answer is the same as what @HotLicks is saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Instruments Time Profiler output, you can see that `NSISEngine` is eating up a ton of CPU. That class is responsible for doing the Auto Layout constraint evaluation and layout calculation.

So it looks like you are using Auto Layout, at least for some of the views.

Are you by any chance removing and re-adding constraints anywhere at runtime? I've seen this exact problem caused by that (can explain more if this is relevant).

If you aren't removing constraints, it sounds like you might have a fairly complex view hierarchy, and if you're using Auto Layout throughout, it's likely that you have a lot of constraints. As you may know, Auto Layout degrades in performance pretty quickly above a certain point due to [super-linear time complexity of solving constraints](http://pilky.me/36/). Check the output of `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` from the debugger to see what your view hierarchy looks like.

I'm not sure what your view controller transition looks like, but you could try removing the disappearing view controller's view from its superview before doing the present. That should prevent it from doing layout calculations as it transitions. If that solves the performance issue, you could [quickly snapshot the view hierarchy](https://coderwall.com/p/56wcfq) and then replace it with a single new UIImageView of the snapshot to display during the transition animation.

(One final thing: are any of your table views using Auto Layout in their cells? do any of these table views have more than ~20 cells?)

Comment: I'm not adding/removing constraints in runtime. I do use auto-layout inside UITableViewCells, but there are usually just about 5-7 cells. The hierarchy is complex, I will check what exactly `recursiveDescription` will tell me.

Comment: I have a scroll view in that view controller and three table views inside that scroll view. Only one of them is visible when transition starts. So I removed the other two from the scroll view on viewWillDisappear and it seemed to improve situation somewhat. I only have autolayout inside the cells, and position all other views manually.

Comment: @sha If you could share the view hierarchy debugger output, that would be helpful. Given that you're using Auto Layout in the cells, this is likely what's eating up all the CPU. If you're still looking for a better solution, can you share some Time Profiler traces where you remove one additional table view from its superview before the transition for each? (including a trace with all 3 table views removed). That may help isolate where exactly the issue lies.

Comment: the view hierarchy is 200 lines in best case and 500-2000 in worst. I've updated the question with my findings. Do you still want to see full output? I can put it somewhere.

Comment: @sha From your explanation, the problem is due to unexpected views hanging around in the view hierarchy. Sharing the output of `recursiveDescription` probably won't help as much as sharing the code for your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` methods, and perhaps your "reload" methods, and any other related ones -- now it's a matter of trying to find out where the extra views are coming from (or why the old ones aren't going away).

Comment: @smileybord: Is it normal that old cells after table was reloaded are still inside the table view as hidden?

Comment: @sha Nope, that's not normal at all. And since table views should recycle cells, you should never have more cells than are visible at any one time.

Comment: @smileybord: Hm... Thanks. I will try to create a simple application to test this behavior and see where I might have a problem.

Answer (score 3):

From your stack, I suspect you've added a large number of views you didn't mean to add. Since it's related to reloads, I would check your reload logic and make sure it doesn't re-add all the views in your hierarchy without removing the previous views. You can <strike>write a quick debug routine</strike> use `-recursiveDescription` to recursively walk the `-subviews` of each view and print them out to see what's in the hierarchy.

It's possible that your issue is in the layer hierarchy rather than the view hierarchy, but the symptoms you describe make me think views.

---

EDIT: From your update, you probably have one of two things going on. Most likely, if these are actual `UITableViewCells` that shouldn't even exist anymore, then you have a retain loop somewhere. Alternately, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` may be incorrect and may be adding new views to an existing cell when it should just be reconfiguring the cell.

In either case, though, 200 views seems a lot of views for a "best case." You may be overusing views in places that you should be doing custom drawing. If the performance is ok, then… ok, but I'd test carefully on your slowest supported devices.

Comment: he should be able to just use  'po [[self view] recursiveDescription]', no?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that method; yes, that would work quite well. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html

Comment: @RobNapier Reasonable answer, but didn't I already cover this (and more) in my [previous answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23484973/796419)?

Comment: Your autolayout ideas may be completely correct, and my view idea may be wrong. But there's a difference between adding views on every reload, and intentionally having a complex view hierarchy. There is also a difference between having a complex autolayout situation and having a huge number of unexpected views. Nothing wrong with your answer; you may be on a much better track than I am. But the first place I'd personally look is in the reload code, not the autolayout or transition code that you suggested (even though you may be completely correct).

Comment: @RobNapier Ah, I see what you're implying in your answer (and how it's slightly different), thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @RobNapier: I updated the question. Reload logic doesn't seem to be bringing extra stuff. My view hierarchy is indeed complex, but for some reason I'm collecting old unused cells as subviews (even though they're hidden)

Answer (score 1):

When presenting another controller your original controller has to be animated out of the window, which causes the `view`'s `frame` to change and probably triggers all `layoutSubviews` methods and your manual adjustments.

You could try to avoid this by deactivating `autoresizesSubviews` in `viewWillDisappear`.

It is not very clean, but then probably all the calculations you are making may not be as well!

Try to optimize them:

- Don't call `layoutSubviews` directly and call `setNeedsLayout` only if really needed.
- Try to replace your manual resizing code with `autoresizingMask` or `autoLayout`.
- Adjust views lazily and only if they are visible and if their `size` and not origin really has changed.
- Don't reload your tables entirely but try to change only individual rows.
- Try to use only a single table view.
- Make sure to reuse cells.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. Some of them are actually require deeper discussions :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem may have something to do with that you are placing UITableView instances inside a UIScrollView. That is explicitly prohibited by Apple's [documentation for UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (surprise!):

> **Important:** You should not embed UIWebView or *UITableView* objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behaviour can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

I suspect that may also mess up table view cell reuse mechanism. Anyway, I'd also recommend to check if you are not 'leaking' any views at all. Keep in mind that even invisible views participate in layout if they are in the view hierarchy.

#### Edit: in response to Update 2

It's evident that cell reuse mechanism is not functioning properly. Try to make sure you are using correct instances of UITableView when dequeueing table view cells from reuse queue (check your data sources).

Comment: Many applications use the same logic. You just need to be careful with this.

Comment: To find out if you are careful enough already, try to get rid of the outer scroll view and see how things perform. Good luck!